# Factorization of quartic forms

Tags: algebraic-geometry, computational-algebra

Consider (complex) quartic forms of three variables that can be factored as product of quadratic forms.
Being the image of a regular map from $\mathbb{P}(S_2) \times \mathbb{P}(S_2)$ to $\mathbb{P}(S_4)$, it is a projective variety. Do we know explicitly polynomials cut it set-theoretically?

Comment: If a plane quartic has 4 singular points in general position, it can be factored in this way. Maybe this observation can be used to write down equations.